# How to select top 3 values in MS Access VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a form with 10 text boxes.  I would like to add a button which, when clicked, would display a message with the average of the top 3 values of the text boxes.  The purpose is to display information to the user before the data is actually saved to the database.

Is there a "top n" function in vba or some clever way of doing this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Name the text boxes in sequence, txtbox1, txtbox2, txtbox3, ... Use a for loop to get individual values and find average. Refer value stored in text box using Me("txtbox" & i).Value

Comment: I need to find the average of the top 3, not all of them.

Comment: You'll need to run though all the values, collect them in an array, then sort them.  Here's some sorting code - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/133135

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just code it yourself:

1) Firstly we need a general sorting routine, so add a new standard module, and something like the following code to it:

```
Sub QuickSort(ByRef Values(), L As Long, R As Long)
  Dim I As Long, J As Long, Pivot As Variant, Temp As Variant
  If (R - L) <= 0 Then Exit Sub
  Do
    I = L
    J = R
    Pivot = Values(CLng(L + (R - L) / 2))
    Do
      Do While Values(I) - Pivot < 0
        I = I + 1
      Loop
      Do While Values(J) - Pivot > 0
        J = J - 1
      Loop
      If I <= J Then
        If I <> J Then
          Temp = Values(I)
          Values(I) = Values(J)
          Values(J) = Temp
        End If
        I = I + 1
        J = J - 1
      End If
    Loop Until I > J
    If L < J Then QuickSort Values, L, J
    L = I
  Loop Until I >= R
End Sub
```

2) You haven't specified how you want to deal with text boxes that don't have a number in them (or indeed, whether the numbers can be floats or should be integers), so let's assume the numbers don't have to be integers, and any invalid input should just be classed as `0`. As such, add the following helper routine to the standard module:

```
Function CDblDef(Value As Variant, Default As Double) As Double
    On Error Resume Next
    CDblDef = Value
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then Value = Default
End Function
```

3) Back in the form code, the average of the top three values can then be calculated like this:

```
Const NumTextBoxCount = 10
Const NumTextBoxPrefix = "txtNum" 'alter as applicable

Function GetNumTextBoxTop3Avg() As Double
  Dim I As Integer, Nums(1 To NumTextBoxCount)
  For I = 1 To NumTextBoxCount
    Nums(I) = CDblDef(Me.Controls(NumTextBoxPrefix & I).Value, 0)
  Next I
  QuickSort Nums, LBound(Nums), UBound(Nums)
  GetNumTextBoxTop3Avg = (Nums(NumTextBoxCount) + Nums(NumTextBoxCount - 1) + Nums(NumTextBoxCount - 2)) / 3
End Function

Private Sub cmdShowTop3Nums_Click()
  MsgBox GetNumTextBoxTop3Avg
End Sub
```